# Efficient way to insert rows in a table busy with deletes/updates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Here is my question: I have 10,000 rows to be inserted into `TableX`. This table is always busy with lots of deletes and updates done by many concurrent users. I am thinking to insert the rows in chunks something like mentioned below:

```
Declare @i int = 1

while @i > 0
begin
   begin transaction
       insert top (1000) id, col1, col2, col3 
       into TableX
           select id, col1, col2, col3 
           from TableY as a
           where not exists (select 1 from TableX as b where a.id = b.id)
       set @i = @@rowcount

   commit transaction
end
```

Now one of the problem I can think of is. If I insert a record and commit it while delete is going on in another connection. There is a chance that my inserted row gets deleted if my record comes in the where condition of delete statement. I guess I will not be the reason for blocking for other users. We are using read committed isolation level.

So my question is should I go ahead and insert these rows or there is something I need to worry about?

Here is DDL statement for TableX and TableY

```
create tableX
(id int primary key,
col1 varchar(100),
col2 varchar(100),
col3 varchar(100)
)
create nonclustered index ncli on TableX(cl1) include (col2,col3)

create tableY
(id int primary key,
col1 varchar(100),
col2 varchar(100),
col3 varchar(100)
)
create nonclustered index ncli on TableY(cl1) include (col2,col3)
```

Thanks ...

Comment: Please provide `DDL` for your tables (with indexes)....

Comment: @Devart :  Please see my edited question.

Comment: `Recovery model = SIMPLE` ?

Comment: Why not just try the simple way to insert 10 000 rows in one statement, It's not like millions of rows...

Comment: it is worth your time to read up on the concurrency models that SQL Server uses: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/15/sql-server-concurrency-basics-guest-post-by-vinod-kumar/ SQL Server by default uses pessimistic concurrency. Try your inserts, and if through monitoring you find problems, or deadlocks occur, then you need to find a solution that that problem rather than preemptively trying to solve a problem you may or may not have.